# reference to std::shared:ptr to avoid reference counting

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, shared-ptr, c++20

I am often facing the argument, that by accepting a `const std::shared_ptr<T>&` one can avoid the reference count increment:

```cpp
void foo(std::shared_ptr<const int> p); 
void foo2(const std::shared_ptr<const int>& p); 

int main(){
   std::shared_ptr<const int> a = std::make_shared<int>(3);

   foo(a);  // calling this function always does reference counting (atomic locks...)
   foo2(a); // calling this function elides reference counting

   std::shared_ptr<int> b = std::make_shared<int>(3);;
   foo2(b); // what happens here? since there is a cast involved creating a temporary ... (NRVO??)
}
```

But I assume that when calling `foo2(b)` reference counting is not elided? However, can the compiler or the std-implementation somehow elide reference counting. Would it make it any better if `foo2(std::move(b))` would be called, for this elision to happen?

Comment: If the function doesn't store the smart pointer elsewhere for later use, it should take a plain reference or pointer, not a smart pointer.

Comment: To illustrate @MaximEgorushkin's point, consider: `void foo3(const int * p); void foo4(const int * const & p);`

Comment: True, but thats not the question.

Comment: Atomic instructions aren’t *locks*, which is kind of the point of them.  (Not that you’re wrong to try to avoid even them.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there will necessarily be a reference count increment prior to entry to `foo2` and a decrement on exit. This is because the parameter `const std::shared_ptr<const int>& p` must refer to a distinct object of type `std::shared_ptr<const int>`, so a temporary must be constructed and destroyed.

Within the language it would not be possible to elide this reference count, because if the argument `b` is modified during the execution of `foo2` the parameter `p` must remain unaffected; it must continue to point to the same `int` object on the heap, which may be modified but not deleted. (This does not apply when `foo2` is called with `a`, as in that case `p` refers directly to `a`, not to a temporary, so modifications to `a` are visible through `p`.)

Passing `std::move(b)` to `foo2` would not be a good idea, because this will leave `b` empty and delete the `int` object when the temporary bound to `p` is destructed.

Answer (score 0):

`std::shared_ptr<const int>` is a different type to `std::shared_ptr<int>`, but there is an implicit converting constructor.

When you call `foo2(b)`, a temporary `std::shared_ptr<const int>` is constructed from `b` and bound to `p`. The constructor increments the reference count, and the destructor decrements it.

When you call `foo1(a)`, `a` is copied into `p`. `p` exists for the duration of the call, and is then destructed. The constructor increments the reference count, and the destructor decrements it.

When you call `foo2(a)`, `a` is bound to `p`. No temporary is constructed, so the reference count isn't changed.

Note that there isn't a reference count in your example, as no `int`s nor `const int`s pointed to by any of the pointers.

Comment: True, that, I changed the exmaple, to include a value.